# Trying to install malabar-mode in emacs, getting "Cannot open load file, malabar-mode"

Tags: java, maven, emacs, elisp, melpa

So I've followed the instructions on the malabar-mode github page.

I have emacs packages set up, with melpa added as a an archive (which is where malabar-mode is). `mvm`'s containing directory is in my `exec-path`, and I have added the following to my `~/.emacs` file, as per the [README's](https://github.com/m0smith/malabar-mode) instructions:

```lisp
(setq semantic-default-submodes '(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode
                                  global-semanticdb-minor-mode
                                  global-semantic-idle-summary-mode
                                  global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode))
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'malabar-mode)
(setq malabar-groovy-lib-dir "/path/to/malabar/lib")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.java\\'" . malabar-mode))
```

However, when I start up emacs, I get:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/kalaracey/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, malabar-mode
```

How can I get malabar mode to work? I am using Emacs 24, which has CEDET built in, so that is why I have added the above code to my `~/.emacs` file (as per the instructions).

Comment: You're probably missing `(package-initialize)` at the top of your `~/.emacs`. I just installed `malabar-mode` and it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you have changed `(setq malabar-groovy-lib-dir "/path/to/malabar/lib")` to an acutal path on your system?

Comment: You are using the Emacs 23.x instructions rather than the 24.

Answer (score 6):

malabar-mode was added to MELPA so you do not need to install it by hand anymore.

To install

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives  
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(package-install 'malabar-mode)
(package-install 'flycheck)      ;; This is optional but nice to have
```

In .emacs.

Because malabar-mode takes so long to load (over 30 seconds on my box), I have it delay loading until I try and find a .java file.

```
(defun malabar-mode-bootstrap ()
  (require 'cedet)
  (require 'semantic)
  (load "semantic/loaddefs.el")
  (semantic-mode 1);;
  (require 'malabar-mode)
  (load "malabar-flycheck")

  (malabar-mode)
  (flycheck-mode))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.java\\'" . malabar-mode-bootstrap))
```

Also, take a look at https://github.com/m0smith/maven-pom-mode for editing the `pom.xml`.